# Why is there an extra "0" at the beginning of every UPC code in openFDA?

Tags: openfda

When I compare images of the package label UPC barcodes with these codes the zero isn't there. Having written an application that stores and uses pharmacy item UPC barcodes, I can assure you the scanned barcodes do not have this extra "0".

Answer (score 1):

It’s likely the leading zero is to make a UPC-A (12 digits) compliant with EAN-13

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number

> The most commonly used EAN standard is the thirteen-digit EAN-13, a superset of the original 12-digit Universal Product Code (UPC-A)